# Problems with Gradient and Bump Node

Tags: materials, normals, bump

I'm trying to make a color gradient. When I use Wave Texture as a color, everything works correctly, the gradients are not sharp.

[image]

But if I connected Wave Texture as Bump Height, the gradients become very sharp.

[image]

How to make the gradient smooth for Bump Node? and what am I doing wrong?

[image] (Blender v 3.3.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your *Bump* 'Height' is over the top, for the dimensions of the mesh. You can either dial down the height itself, or adjust 'Distance', which is just a height multiplier.. same thing.

('Strength' is a simple linear mix between the RGB=XYZ(No Bump) and RGB=XYZ(Bump).. subtly different, less easy to interpret physically. I treat it as a purely visual effect, only if needed, otherwise 1)

One tip for <kbd>Shift</kbd>-slide-adjusting tiny values.. pop them through a multiplier on the way in. You can always type in the right value once you've found it:

[image]

Comment: what does OTT stand for?

Comment: @Chris [Over The Top] ! My bad.. thought that one crossed language-barriers :)

Comment: @Chris google any initialism together with `urban dictionary`, and you will reliably find a definition for each.

Comment: Yep, but I found dozens of explanations…when I searched for abbreviations

Comment: @Chris when you search on Google or wikipedia, you will find a lot of various abbreviations indeed, but on Urban Dictionary IRC initialisms will gravitate towards the top.

Comment: Modifying the distance to small numbers using a multiplication totally did the trick for me. Thanks @RobinBetts!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>To my knowledge, *Bump* is used for sudden changes in surface height to create sharp bevels.</strike> I've seen techniques that averages multiple bumps to blur it, but maybe you want to try a setup like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: but if plugin a simple noise texture, i got this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AJIa.jpg and maybe i am wrong but this doesn't look like sharp edges to me...

Comment: AFAIK, _Bump_ approximates normals by passing heights through a  [Sobel filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).. or something very like it. It actually makes a _better_ approximation of normals on smooth gradients than on sharp ones, because it's based on discrete samples. (As always, waiting to be shot down :) )

Comment: @RobinBetts exactly, it's an edge detection algorithm, that's why I thought it's supposed to create sharp edges, but somehow this is not the case as your answer shows... 

Comment: Hi @MarkusvonBroady .! . I'm always open to correction.. it seems to me that the output of Sobel is a discrete approximation of (dh/dx, dh/dy), whatever the gradient.. it just happens to throw up values which can be put through a threshold to detect edges.